# Push signed transaction without packed transaction data in EOS?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio.token

In ripple, bitcoin and ethereum you can sign a transaction and push/broadcast signed transaction hash only. That effectively represents the whole transaction. for example

```
12000022800000002400000001201B7FFFFFFF614000000011E1A300684000000000B71B00732102823A1B036701A084E5F0A924CBDDD164B9772697B1115524A59A64AE0A9ADAF1744730450221008CB6CEF2F851A3BA6CAE744C8680A797C6B5BE2AC166822EB6293BC8BFB8A197022067D98766D5D670D9919386DE4E7FB4
```

Is it possible in EOS as well?

I have signed a transaction and this is my signed transaction which I want to push:

```
{
 "transaction_id":"3992f5daa5d8fe741771939948d8d85ac1a76da7110d66caaf7ff3a9be70b2a9",
"broadcast":false,
"transaction":{
  "compression":"none",
  "transaction":{
     "expiration":"2018-12-11T13:51:20",
     "ref_block_num":45983,
     "ref_block_prefix":71589329,
     "max_net_usage_words":0,
     "max_cpu_usage_ms":0,
     "delay_sec":0,
     "context_free_actions":[

     ],
     "actions":[
        "transfer"
     ],
     "transaction_extensions":[

     ]
  },
  "signatures":[
     "SIG_K1_Kb7o3xyCmTAqb7o7Nuea3og3Df9u9nbMB4U6idiyhKnC3CVqLhfb3GnuqX5mCuFY3powY9ARHszwo9xXinrzp6Z25ZUZHt"
  ]
}
}
```

Can I just used signature to push the transaction or do I have to send the Packed Transaction data as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need the packed transaction data.  If you add the flags `--print-request` and `--print-response` ([example of this](https://gist.github.com/lucas-maicoin/bf29af19f6a488f2509d74b406e1f127)), you can see how the signature process works.  It requires ([docs](https://developers.eos.io/keosd/reference#sign_transaction)):

- `txn` - string
- `keys` - string
- `id` - string

---

The [**push transaction RPC API call requires**](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference):

- `signatures` - array of signatures required to authorize transaction
- `compression` - compression used, usually false
- `packed_context_free_data` - string
- `packed_trx` - string

---

In cleos, you can use the `-d` and `--return-packed` flags together to print to the console a signed transaction.

```
-d,--dont-broadcast  - don't broadcast transaction to the network (just print to stdout)
--return-packed      - used in conjunction with --dont-broadcast to get the packed transaction
```

So I did this for a simple contract:

```
cleos -u http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80 push action -d --return-packed eosezchatnat sendmsg '["eosezchatnat","hi"]' -p eosezchatnat

{
  "signatures": [
    "SIG_K1_K9PsoNw9AGY7YEmuQkgmC1i3qfuLvGvUZTzc2dHZ9Bjoru6KZEQJAZrYRFVHw22TG1dthryxfW4m5YWcaCDeCLNBHPeDqQ"
  ],
  "compression": "none",
  "packed_context_free_data": "",
  "packed_trx": "56de0f5c82dc4a508078000000000190cdcca6a1af3055000000806199a6c20190cdcca6a1af305500000000a8ed32320b90cdcca6a1af305502686900"
}
```

You could then send that transaction to the chain.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out as well. I used /v1/chain/abi_json_to_bin -X POST -d '{"code":"eosio.token", "action":"transfer", "args":{"from":"alice", "to":"bob", "quantity":"10.0000 EOS", "memo":"gift from alice to bob"}}' to get packed transaction.